# What does it mean to say a thread may be running but it will not execute any instruction beyond GC Safe Point?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a vague idea of GC Safe point. I tried to do find in google but I don't see any example explaining how exactly GC safe point works in terms of a java code. So what I would like to know

- 1.can a thread keep running beyond GC safe point?
- Assuming it can what does it mean by it will not execute any byte code instruction?

Any help would be apreciated

Edit:
  I know there are similar question in Stack Overflow, but that does not answer my question

Comment: I case the linked answers really don't answer your question, edit it and make it clear so it can be reopened. As it stands, I'm rather unsure what you mean...